# Audio and video are interrupted when the window is minimized or the screen is turned off in Chrome Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

My player written using the video tag in HTML5, as well as an audio player written using the Audio object in JS stops playing when the phone screen turns off or the Chrome application is minimized. I have seen that on some sites this does not happen when playing. How could I change this behavior? I searched the Internet for information, but I didn't find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52028940/150978